# Notifications recieved from MPMoviePlayerController after tapping on next/ previous button. or How to disable next/previous in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotifications

I googled for this problem and tried out many possible ways but didn't work out.Please help me to solve this. What my problem is

1. What are the notifications recieved after tapping on next/previous  buttons in MPMoviePlayerController.
2. Can I recognise the notifications from the above is either next or previous.

If I am not able to accomplish the above

1. How can i disable next and prev actions in MPMoviePlayerController(in
   swift).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I'm also looking for answers to problem 2. As for the first problem, hope my [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34759244/2918210) would help:)